# Image captcha module not showing in admin after updating Drupal to 7.35

Tags: 7, updating, captcha

I have a site with [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module installed and Image captcha submodule working perfectly before upgrading.

I followed the recommended steps, and even did it in a nearly identical test site. Everything worked perfectly in the test site. But when I applied the changes (updating from previous core version) in production, I realized that Image captcha is not only not working anymore: it even doesn't appear as submodule in Admin.

The folder is there but is no longer detected. I am thinking of reinstalling the complete Captcha module, but I am very worried about the rest of modules.

Going back to my backup of my database is not an option as I realized the problem after 2 days and that means losing a lot of data (if I would restore my backup).

Any tip on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the upgrade has renamed the path of submodule Image captcha to `sites/all/modules/captcha0/image_captcha` instead of the correct `sites/all/modules/captcha/image_captcha` (renamed filename value in table system of database. Physical path not changed). After that I have been forced to reinstall the module.

This is simply not serious, This seems a Drupal or a module bug and I have spent very bad hours trying to figure out what went wrong when I followed steps one by one and was very cautious.